# UVMap transfer of displacement map

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, displacement

my problem is, that I have a texture set and a mesh I should apply the textures to, but they have different UV mappings. It is no option to change the UVMap of the mesh, so the only chance I have is to remap the texture to the UVMap of the mesh. I know how to bake e.g. the diffuse layer onto a second UVMap, but there is no option to do this for displacement maps. I bet there is a trick also to map float textures to another UVMap but failed to find the workflow yet. Can anyone help me to find the trick or is there no way to do it?

Comment: You can use multiple UVMaps for render with the UVMap node. You can also bake texture from one UVMap to an other with is. If you want to do the second option, and there is no bake option for that kind of texture, then you can put it in the Color socket of the shader node, bake and save it, then use the result as a displacement map. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried exactly that, but it doesn't not exactly work as expected. My displacement map is a float image with also negative numbers, if I plug this into Color and bake the diffuse Color, the output is mapped to a range [0, 1]. This kinda works, but destroys my original height information. Is there a trick to preserve the range, too?

Comment: It seems to work when using the Emission channel to bake.